# Get Latitude & Longitude From an Address using csv file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, csv, latitude-longitude

how can i get lat-/longitude of an address during an CSV file reading ? reading addresses from a csv and write all lat/lan into csv file.

```
<?php
function readCSV($csvFile){
 $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);
return $line_of_text;
}
$csvFile = 'list1.csv';

$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var address = <?php echo json_encode($csv); ?>;
var value1 = '';
var csv_data=[];
$.each(address , function(index, val) {
jQuery.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
data: {'address': val[1],'sensor':false},
success: function(data){
    if(data.results.length){
    document.write(val[1]+"==Latitude:"+data.results[0].geometry.location.lat 
   +'==');

document.write("Longitude:"+data.results[0].geometry.location.lng+'<br>');
csv_data.push({"address":val[1],"Latitude":data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,"Longitude":data.results[0].geometry.location.lng});
    }
}
});

});

var csv_data1 = JSON.stringify(csv_data);

$.ajax({  
type: 'POST',  
url: 'res.php', 
data: csv_data1,
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
});
});
</script>
```

i have 400000 address are available and need to get all Latitude & Longitude,
 Any free API?

Answer (score 1):

[SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com) has an API that can take a csv file of addresses and give you all sorts of information about them, including Latitude and Longitude. You can find the relevant documentation [here](https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugins/smartylist).

SmartyStreets lets you try out their service for free (up to 250 lookups per month). For your volume of addresses, you naturally would need to buy more lookups. I don't know of any completely free API that would let you process 400,000 addresses.

There is a handy [website plugin](https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugins/website) you can use, as well as the [SmartyStreets JavaScript SDK](https://smartystreets.com/docs/sdk/javascript) (which I helped write). Disclosure: I am a software developer at SmartyStreets.